# Object-Oriented Programming with Attribute Error

Tags: python

This is my first non-MATLAB programming language so I am having some trouble with object-oriented programming. Specifically, I am working on a program that simulates a blackjack game. It was functioning but I have tried adding some new functionality in allowing players to make bets

To surmise, BJ Player is an object that was a collection of card objects.  Def_init used to just have self and names as parameters, but I added startingmonies (starting money that the player is wagering.) The superclass of BJ player is ultimately BJ hand. I am now getting an error when calling a method to add a card to that hand. Below is where the error o

```
class BJ_Game(object):
""" A Blackjack Game. """
def __init__(self, names, startingmonies):      
    self.players = []
    for name in names:
        player = BJ_Player(name)
        spot = names.index(name)
        startingscratch = startingmonies[spot]
        player_with_money = (name, startingscratch,0)
        self.players.append(player_with_money)
```

This is where the error originates (cards module that is imported into the BJ module used above):

```
class Hand(object):
""" A hand of playing cards. """
def __init__(self):
    self.cards = []

def __str__(self):
    if self.cards:
       rep = ""
       for card in self.cards:
           rep += str(card) + "\t"
    else:
        rep = "<empty>"
    return rep

def clear(self):
    self.cards = []

def add(self, card):
    self.cards.append(card)

def give(self, card, other_hand):
    self.cards.remove(card)
    other_hand.add(card)
```

This is the error that I get.:
 line 47, in give
    other_hand.add(card)

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'add'

I get this error when trying to deal cards. Everything else worked before so the only real change that I made is adding the bet parameter. I researched this issue and was not able to gain a strong understanding. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here is some more information. I think the error is happening because I changed self.players to be a list of tuples. I am not sure how to fix this though.

```
for index, player in enumerate(self.players):
        flag = 1
        while flag:
            try:
                (name, players_cache,bet) = player
                print(players_cache)
                print("Current player:",name)
                bet = int(input("Please select how much this player would like to wager: "))
                if bet <= 0:
                    print("Bet must be greater than 0")
                elif bet <= players_cache:
                    flag = 0
                    players_cache-=bet
                    player = (name,players_cache,bet)
                    self.players[index] = player
                else:
                    print("Insufficient funds. PLayer only has",players_cache,"dollars available")
            except ValueError:
                print("Input must be a number\n")


    # deal initial 2 cards to everyone
    self.deck.deal(self.players + [self.dealer], per_hand = 2)
```

I get another part of the error here.
line 169, in play
    self.deck.deal(self.players + [self.dealer], per_hand = 2)

Here is the full error block. Sorry for not showing all of it before:

line 262, in 
    main()
  line 258, in main
    game.play(max_Cards)
   line 169, in play
    self.deck.deal(self.players + [self.dealer], per_hand = 2)
   line 65, in deal
    self.give(top_card, hand)
   line 47, in give
    other_hand.add(card)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'add'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a `tuple` object to `give` method, instead of a Hand instance explaining why `add` method is not defined. Since you haven't mentioned the call to give method in your code, I couldn't give the pointer to the exact line.

Comment: line 65, in deal
      self.give(top_card, hand)

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the error, `other_hand` must be a tuple, so you cannot use `add()` in this case. Tuples cannot be changed by the code, they must be directly changed by the person making the code. A tuple is like this:

```
tuple = (var1, var2, ..., varx)
```

Basically a list but with parentheses and cannot be changed by the code. So you must make sure `other_hand` is a list instead.

Comment: I think I understand the difference between tuples and lists but I don't understand why this worked before and not now

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help people! Changed the bets to attributes and it fixed my problem.